# How to implement the same method in classes derived from an abstract base?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods

I have an abstract class `Job` and other classes that implement it like:

`Waiter` and `Builder`, all of them implement my function in the same way.

For example:

```
Waiter::changeScore()
{
    score += top_score;
}
```

How may I prevent this kind of code duplication?

Constraints:

1. I want to keep `Job` abstract.
2. Each `Waiter` or `Builder` has its own `top_score` value (It differs between classes and objects of the same class).

Comment: If I write the implementation inside Job that will fix everything but won't job be non-abstract by doing this?

Comment: @AdrianMole Isn't the definition of polymorphism and abstract class that all functions should be virtual?

Comment: No. At least one method should be, that's all.

Comment: I think I got confused by reading other articles, please post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all member functions of an abstract class need to be pure virtual (as long as at least one is). Your `changeScore` member is an ideal candidate as a 'real' base class function. Further, not only does it not need to be **pure** `virtual`, it doesn't even need to be `virtual` at all (unless you want your polymorphism to change what a *pointer to a* derived class will see, for that function).

As each class (or object) will have its own *value* of `top_score` (as you have stated), then that (data) member can also be part of the 'abstract' base class.

You can even add a single 'dummy' pure virtual function in your base class (which is never intended to be used, even by a derived class), just to make sure that instances aren't accidentally created. For example, your `Job` class could have a member:

```cpp
    virtual int Dummy() = 0;
```

Then, any derived class *must* have an override for that (however trivial), or the compiler won't allow you to declare an instance of that class. So, your `Waiter` class would need something like:

```cpp
    int Dummy override { return 1; }
```

The following code sample may help/demonstrate the idea:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // So we can use smart pointers

class Job {
public:
    int score{ 0 }, top_score{ 0 };
public:
    Job() { }
    virtual ~Job() = default;
    virtual void Dummy() = 0; // This is sufficient to make the class abstract!
    void changeScore() {
        score += top_score;
    }
    virtual void showName() {
        std::cout << "Generic Job" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Waiter : public Job {
public:
    Waiter(int top = 5) { top_score = top; }
    ~Waiter() override = default;
    void Dummy() override { } // We need this in order to use Waiter
    void showName() override {
        std::cout << "Waiter" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Builder : public Job {
public:
    Builder(int top = 10) { top_score = top; }
    ~Builder() override = default;
    void Dummy() override { } // We need this in order to use Builder  
    void showName() override {
        std::cout << "Builder" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Waiter w{ 6 }; // OK - uses explicit value for 'top' parameter
    Builder b;     // OK - uses default value for 'top' parameter
 //   Job j;       // ERROR - Cannot instantiate abstract class
    w.changeScore();
    b.changeScore();
    std::cout << w.score << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.score << std::endl;

    // Also, using pointers...
 // Job* pj = new Job;      // ERROR - Cannot instantiate abstract class
    Job* pw = new Waiter;   // OK - Now we can make use of polymorphism...
    Job* pb = new Builder;  // ...with either of these 2 "Job" pointers!
    pw->showName();
    pb->showName();
    delete pw;
    delete pb;

    // Polymorphism also works with smart pointers (which you SHOULD be using) ...
//  std::unique_ptr<Job> upj = std::make_unique<Job>(); // ERROR - Allocating an object of abstract class
    std::unique_ptr<Job> upw = std::make_unique<Waiter>(15);
    upw->changeScore();
    std::cout << upw->score << ": ";
    upw->showName();
    std::unique_ptr<Job> upb = std::make_unique<Builder>(42);
    upb->changeScore();
    std::cout << upb->score << ": ";
    upb->showName();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the method in the base class:

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qmTizjPVSw2xrQ1H)

```
class Job {
    private:
    int score;
    int top_score;

    protected:
    //protected constructor to be inherited by derived classes
    Job(int top_score) : top_score(top_score) {}

    //one pure virtual method is enough to make the class abstract
    virtual void some_method() = 0;

    public:   
    void changeScore() { //single method implementation
        score += top_score;
    }
    //to use polymorphism you must use a virtual destructor, unless you use shared_ptr
    virtual ~Job(){}   
};

class Waiter : public Job {
    public:
    Waiter(int top_score) : Job(top_score) {}

    // pure virtual methods must be overridden in all derived classes
    void some_method() override{}
};

class Builder : public Job {
    public:
    Builder(int top_score) : Job(top_score) {}
    void some_method() override{}
};
```

`changeScore()` will be implemented in the abstract class and will be usable by all derived classes.

```
Waiter w(10); //top_score 10
Buider b(20); // top_score 20
b.changeScore();
w.changeScore();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `changeScore` method a pure virtual method AND provide an implementation. This would look like this:

```
class Job {
int score{0};
int top_score{0};
public:
  virtual void changeScore() = 0;
};

void Job::changeScore()
{
    score += top_score;
}
```

Then you can call the `changeScore` method of the `Job` base class in the child classes like this:

```
class Waiter : public Job {
public:
  virutal void changeScore() override {
    Job::changeScore();
  }
};
```

This way if you want to change `changeScore`, you do not need to change all the implementations in the child classes, but you can just change the implementation in the `Job` class.
This way you do not need any dummy methods and the `Job` class remains abstract, while the override in the child classes is trivial and you have a single implementation if you ever want to change it.

EDIT:
If you are wondering where this `override` keyword comes from, it is introduced in C++11. Since I do not know which C++ version you are using I just wanted to point that out.
You can read about the override specifier [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)

EDIT II:
Regarding that ever child class has its own `top_score`, you should set this via the constructor of those child classes.
Like this:

```
class Job {
protected:
int top_score{0};
Job(top) : top_score(top) {}
...
};

class Waiter : public Job {
public:
  Waiter(int top): Job(top) {}
  ...
};
```

This way each child class has its own version of `top_score`

EDIT III:
Putting it all together the classes would look something like this:

```
class Job {
protected:
  int score{0};
  int top_score{0};
  Job(top) : top_score(top) {}
public:
  virtual void changeScore() = 0;
};

void Job::changeScore()
{
    score += top_score;
}

class Waiter : public Job {
public:
  Waiter(int top): Job(top) {}

  virutal void changeScore() override {
    Job::changeScore();
  }
};
```